# How to prove that $(1 - x)^y \leq 1$, When $1 > x > 0 \wedge y \geq 1$?

Tags: inequalities

The statement in the question is obviously true. But when I tried

```
FullSimplify[(1 - x)^y <= 1, 1 > x > 0 && y >= 1]
```

I got

```
(*(1 - x)^y <= 1*)
```

Is there any way to get this done through Mathematica?

Comment: Taking logs on both sides seems to help: `In[126]:= FullSimplify[y*Log[(1 - x)] <= 0, 1 > x > 0 && y >= 1]

Out[126]= True`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Reduce[(1 - x)^y > 1 && 1 > x > 0 && y >= 1]

(* False  *)
```

Have fun!

Comment: That is rather weird. How come `Reduce[(1 - x)^y <= 1 && 1 > x > 0 && y >= 1]` does not work?

Comment: Come on, if one statement is false, the opposite one is true. What is your aim: to solve a problem, or to do it in one special way?

Comment: @ablmf In what sense did your variant fail to work?

Comment: @DanielLichtblau It does not return True.

Comment: @ablmf: `Reduce` doesn't return a True or False value unless the listed statement is *automatically* true or *automatically* False.  In your version, the first clause `(1 - x)^y <= 1` does follow automatically from the other two, which means if you run  `Reduce[(1 - x)^y <= 1 && 1 > x > 0 && y >= 1, Reals]`, you get back `1 > x > 0 && y >= 1`.  But there are values of $x$ and $y$ for which this latter statement isn't true, so it can't be reduced further.

Answer (score 1):

What about the following?

```
      Reduce[(1 - x)^y <= 1 && 1 > x > 0 && y >= 1, {x, y}, Reals]
 (* 0 < x < 1 && y >= 1 *)
```